# Spark Dataframes: Add Conditional column to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

I want to add a conditional column `Flag` to dataframe A. When the following two conditions are satisfied, add 1 to `Flag`, otherwise 0:

1. `num` from dataframe A is in between `numStart` and `numEnd` from dataframe B.
2. If the above condition satifies, check if `include` is 1.

DataFrame A (it's a very big dataframe, containing millions of rows):

```
+----+------+-----+------------------------+
|num |food  |price|timestamp               |
+----+------+-----+------------------------+
|1275|tomato|1.99 |2018-07-21T00:00:00.683Z|
|145 |carrot|0.45 |2018-07-21T00:00:03.346Z|
|2678|apple |0.99 |2018-07-21T01:00:05.731Z|
|6578|banana|1.29 |2018-07-20T01:11:59.957Z|
|1001|taco  |2.59 |2018-07-21T01:00:07.961Z|
+----+------+-----+------------------------+
```

DataFrame B (it's a very small DF, containing only 100 rows):

```
+----------+-----------+-------+
|numStart  |numEnd     |include|
+----------+-----------+-------+
|0         |200        |1      |
|250       |1050       |0      |
|2000      |3000       |1      |
|10001     |15001      |1      |
+----------+-----------+-------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----+------+-----+------------------------+----------+
|num |food  |price|timestamp               |Flag      |
+----+------+-----+------------------------+----------+
|1275|tomato|1.99 |2018-07-21T00:00:00.683Z|0         |
|145 |carrot|0.45 |2018-07-21T00:00:03.346Z|1         |
|2678|apple |0.99 |2018-07-21T01:00:05.731Z|1         |
|6578|banana|1.29 |2018-07-20T01:11:59.957Z|0         |
|1001|taco  |2.59 |2018-07-21T01:00:07.961Z|0         |
+----+------+-----+------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you tried joining the dataframes based on the condition you describe in item (i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can left-join `dfB` to `dfA` based on the condition you described in (i), then build a `Flag` column using `withColumn` and the `coalesce` function to "default" to 0:

- Records for which a match was found would use the `include` value of the matching `dfB` record
- Records for which there was no match would have `include=null`, and per your requirement such records should get `Flag=0`, so we use `coalesce` which in case of null returns the default value with a literal `lit(0)`

Lastly, get rid of the `dfB` columns which are of no interest to you:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._ // assuming "spark" is your SparkSession

dfA.join(dfB, $"num".between($"numStart", $"numEnd"), "left")
  .withColumn("Flag", coalesce($"include", lit(0)))
  .drop(dfB.columns: _*)
  .show()

// +----+------+-----+--------------------+----+
// | num|  food|price|           timestamp|Flag|
// +----+------+-----+--------------------+----+
// |1275|tomato| 1.99|2018-07-21T00:00:...|   0|
// | 145|carrot| 0.45|2018-07-21T00:00:...|   1|
// |2678| apple| 0.99|2018-07-21T01:00:...|   1|
// |6578|banana| 1.29|2018-07-20T01:11:...|   0|
// |1001|  taco| 2.59|2018-07-21T01:00:...|   0|
// +----+------+-----+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol coalesce" and "cannot resolve symbol lit" error.
Also if I may ask, what is the rationale behind coalesce on the column "include"?

Comment: What Spark version are you using? And have you included the first import statement (importing `functions._`) in your code? That's where the `lit` function should come from. As for the use of `coalesce`: added an explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two dataframes together on the first condition while keeping all rows in dataframe A (i.e. with a left join, see code below). After the join, the `include` column can be renamed `Flag` and any NaN values inside it are set to 0. The two extra columns, `numStart` and `numEnd` are dropped.

The code can thus be written as follows:

```
A.join(B, $"num" >= $"numStart" && $"num" <= $"numEnd", "left")
  .withColumnRenamed("include", "Flag")
  .drop("numStart", "numEnd")
  .na.fill(Map("Flag" -> 0))
```